# H2 Client couldn't connect to the server

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, h2

I am trying to connect to H2 Server started on the same machine using java. I started the H2 server in mixed mode. While connecting to the server I am getting Error.

The code to start the server is:

```
Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpSSL").start();
```

The code to connect to the server is:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1/~/Data/test", "", "");
```

The Error is:

Connection is broken: "unexpected status 352518912" [90067-197]

Anybody please help me with this. I am stuck at this for two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ssl` protocol instead of `tcp` in the URL, because you use an encrypted socked on the server.

`"jdbc:h2:ssl://127.0.0.1/~/Data/test"`

Please also note that database cannot be created remotely by default in recent versions of H2 due to security reasons. You need to create the database on the server side with a local url such as `"jdbc:h2:~/Data/test"`, it's enough to open and close a connection to it.

Also I hope that empty password is only for that example code in the question. If you have a database that has an user with ADMIN privileges (username and password from the first connection that creates the database are used to create such user) and an empty or weak password (or if you enable the remote database creation), anyone, who can connect to that port, will get full access to your server process and this process most likely already has the same access to your system as you, so you effectively create a remote security hole with `-tcpAllowOthers` and such passwords.